# Do you need a web server to run a production build of a react app on a VPS?

Tags: reactjs, npm, vps, truffle

I have built a react app using a truffle box that uses create-react app. I can get the app running on my local host but I can't see it on my VPS when I go to the IP address of my VPS and I run exactly the same commands and I get the same output in the terminal. I go in to my client dir and run `npm start`. I have tried to make a build and run the build through an http server in the client dir and the root folder of the VPS.

I run

```
serve -s build
```

[image]

All I can see is the index of the build in the browser when I try and serve the build through a webserver. When I run `npm start` on my localhost I can view my app but it doesn't work on my VPS. Please help me I've been struggling with this for days and its the last part of my project.

Answer (score 1):

You need a webserver in any case.
When you do a local development, you do use webpack dev server (which is inside of create react app).
For the production, you need to make a production build and serve it for example by nginx. Here some details how to create production build with CRA https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build

On your screenshot, you don't see your site, because there is no entry point in your folder. By default it should be index.html